# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at main method declaration

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to get some old C++ code up and running. I've gotten it to compile without error, but it immediately segfaults when I run, without entering main. When I use gdb to find out where things are going wrong, I find the following:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/dreens/Documents/OH/extrabuncher2/ParaOHSB 
Reading symbols for shared libraries +++. done

Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x00007fff5636581c
0x000000010000151e in main (argc=1, argv=0x100000ad0) at ParaMainOHSlowerBuncher.cc:13
13  int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000010000151e in main (argc=1, argv=0x100000ad0) at ParaMainOHSlowerBuncher.cc:13
(gdb)
```

Does anyone know what could cause a memory access issue right at the start of the main method?

The code is rather large, but here is the file containing the main method. Could the included .hh and .cc files be a part of the problem? Should I attach them?

Thanks!
David

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "MoleculeEnsemble.hh"
#include "SlowerForceLoadOH32.cc"
#include "SlowerForceLoadOH12.cc"
//#include "SlowerForceLoad3mmBuncher.cc"
#include "SlowerForceLoad4mmBuncher.cc"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//int main(){

cout << "Ahhhh!" << endl;
/******Parallel Crap********/
/*
int totalnodes = 0;
int mynode = 0;

MPI_Status status;
MPI_Init(&argv,&argc);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&totalnodes);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&mynode);

srand(time(NULL)*mynode);

*/
/******Distribution Parameters *******/
long MoleculeNumber = long(5e4);
double Xcenter = 0;
double Ycenter = 0;
double Zcenter = 0;
double DeltaX = 0.0015;
double DeltaY = 0.0015;
double DeltaZ = 0.01;
int FlatX = 1;
int FlatY = 1;
int FlatZ = 1;
double vXcenter = 0;
double vYcenter = 0;
double vZcenter = 406;
double Vcalc = 406;
double vZfinal = 0;
double DeltavX = 2;
double DeltavY = DeltavX;
double DeltavZ = 40;
int FlatvX = 0;
int FlatvY = 0;
int FlatvZ = 0;

int TimeArrayOnly = 0; //Outputs only Time Array
double TimeOffset = 0; //Adds valve-skimmer flight time to ToF array

/*******Overtone Parameters********/
int S = 1;      //parameter S=Vz/Vswitch as defined by VDM et al.
int JILAOT = 0; //JILAOT is either 0 or 1, denoting whether or not to use special switching

/*******Hexapole Parameters********/
double VSD = 0.06;
double Voltage = 2000;
double HexRadius = .00268;
double HexStart = .0238;
double HexEnd = .083170;//0.089103;
double HexOn = 1e-6;
double HexOff = 203e-6;//224e-6; 212 for current data; Good = 243e-6 for 408m/s
double DeltaT = 1e-6;
double DeltaTSeqGen = 1e-9; //Need to use smaller time steps for finding the time sequence
double DetectionTime = HexOff; //Use to fake out hex code
double TriggerLatency = 0;//170e-9;

/*******Detection Parameters*******/
double DetectionPosition = double(0.9319);//0.257480; <- for viewing at 31.5 |||||   0.9428; <-Mag trap(4stages), .9319 <-MagTrap(3Stages)
double IrisWidth = 0.008;//31.5 0.0023 //PostSlower.015;
double LaserRadius = .001;

/*****Bunching Paramaters******/
int BunchNumber = 0;
int NumberUsed = 0;

/*****Timing Variables*********/
time_t start, finish;
time( &start);

/*****Molecule Parameters******/
double mass =double(17*1.672e-27);


/******ToF Detection Arrays and Slowing Parameters *********/
double Phi = double(34.2);
double PhiEB = double(0);
int NumberOfStages = int(142/S); //Use 142 for Big machine
int EBStages = 3;                //Larger Add-on stages at end of slower
double BuncherScale = 1;
double Time[int(1e7)];
int ToFSignal32[int(1e7)];
int ToFSignal12[int(1e7)];
double TimeArray[800];
double VExit[800];
double Average32[7];
double Average12[7];
int LOST[200];
/*************Finished ToF Detection Arrays and Slowing Parameters ********/



/******Force Arrays********/
int Xnumber = 111;
int Ynumber = 21;
int Znumber = 21;
int FLength = Xnumber*Ynumber*Znumber;
double AXxDT[FLength];
double AYxDT[FLength];
double AZxDT[FLength];
double AZxDTSeqGen[FLength];
SlowerForceLoadOH32(AZxDT, AYxDT, AXxDT); //Note how Z and X are placed in this function. My matlab code calls the longitudnal dimension X, here it is Z
double DTovermass = DeltaT/mass;

for(int j = 0; j <FLength; j++){
    AXxDT[j] = DTovermass*AXxDT[j];
    AYxDT[j] = DTovermass*AYxDT[j];
    AZxDT[j] = DTovermass*AZxDT[j];
        AZxDTSeqGen[j] = DeltaTSeqGen*AZxDT[j]/DeltaT;
}


double AXxDT12[FLength];
double AYxDT12[FLength];
double AZxDT12[FLength];

SlowerForceLoadOH12(AZxDT12, AYxDT12, AXxDT12); //Note how Z and X are placed in this function. My matlab code calls the longitudnal dimension X, here it is Z
for(int j = 0; j <FLength; j++){    
        AXxDT12[j] = DTovermass*AXxDT12[j];
        AYxDT12[j] = DTovermass*AYxDT12[j];
        AZxDT12[j] = DTovermass*AZxDT12[j];
}

/********Load Extra Buncher Forces*********/
int XnumberEB = 251;
int YnumberEB = 41;
int ZnumberEB = 41;
int FLengthEB = XnumberEB*YnumberEB*ZnumberEB;
double AXxDTEB[FLengthEB], AYxDTEB[FLengthEB], AZxDTEB[FLengthEB], AZxDTSeqGenEB[FLengthEB];
SlowerForceLoad4mmBuncher(AZxDTEB, AYxDTEB, AXxDTEB);

for(int j = 0; j <FLengthEB; j++)
{
        AXxDTEB[j] = DTovermass*AXxDTEB[j]/BuncherScale;
        AYxDTEB[j] = DTovermass*AYxDTEB[j]/BuncherScale;
        AZxDTEB[j] = DTovermass*AZxDTEB[j]/BuncherScale;
        AZxDTSeqGenEB[j] = DeltaTSeqGen*AZxDTEB[j]/(DeltaT*BuncherScale);
}




/********* End All initiliazation ***************************/


/************Beginning Calculation *************************/
//Create Molecule Ensemble
MoleculeEnsemble Alice(MoleculeNumber,Xcenter,Ycenter,Zcenter,DeltaX,DeltaY,DeltaZ,FlatX,FlatY,FlatZ,vXcenter,vYcenter,vZcenter,DeltavX,DeltavY,DeltavZ,FlatvX,FlatvY,FlatvZ);
//MoleculeEnsemble Bob(MoleculeNumber,Xcenter,Ycenter,Zcenter,DeltaX,DeltaY,DeltaZ,FlatX,FlatY,FlatZ,vXcenter,vYcenter,vZcenter,DeltavX,DeltavY,DeltavZ,FlatvX,FlatvY,FlatvZ);

//Generate the Timing Sequence
Alice.TimeArrayGeneratorWithBuncher(Vcalc,Phi,PhiEB,TimeArray,VExit,AZxDTSeqGen,AZxDTSeqGenEB,HexOff,DeltaTSeqGen,BunchNumber,vZfinal,NumberUsed,NumberOfStages,S,EBStages);

/*if(mynode == 0){
cout << "Slowing utilized " << NumberUsed << " stages, yielding a final velocity of " << VExit[NumberUsed] << " m/s." << endl;
cout << endl;
for(int kk = 0; kk < NumberOfStages; kk++){cout << kk << " , " << TimeArray[kk] << " , " << VExit[kk] << endl;}
}*/

/*Alice.MoleculeEnsemble_Averager(Average32);
Bob.MoleculeEnsemble_Averager(Average12);

cout << "Processor: " << mynode << "\t" << sqrt(pow(Average32[3],2)+pow(Average32[4],2)) << ", " << sqrt(pow(Average12[3],2)+pow(Average12[4],2));
cout << " Mean = " << Average32[6] << ", " << Average12[6] << endl << endl << endl;
*/

if(TimeArrayOnly!=1)
{
    //Fly the Ensemble through the hexapole
    Alice.HexapoleFlightOH(Voltage, HexRadius, HexStart, HexEnd, HexOn, HexOff, DeltaT, double(3/2), DetectionTime); 
    //Bob.HexapoleFlightOH(Voltage, HexRadius, HexStart, HexEnd, HexOn, HexOff, DeltaT, double(1/2), DetectionTime);

    /*
    Alice.MoleculeEnsemble_Averager(Average32);
    Bob.MoleculeEnsemble_Averager(Average12);

    cout << "Processor: " << mynode << "\t" << sqrt(pow(Average32[3],2)+pow(Average32[4],2)) << ", " << sqrt(pow(Average12[3],2)+pow(Average12[4],2));
    cout << " Mean = " << Average32[6] << ", " << Average12[6] << endl << endl << endl;
    */

    //Fly the Ensemble through the slower 
    Alice.SlowerFlight(LOST, Time, ToFSignal32, Phi, TimeArray, DeltaT, AXxDT, AYxDT, AZxDT, AXxDTEB, AYxDTEB, AZxDTEB, Xnumber, Ynumber, Znumber, DetectionPosition, IrisWidth, LaserRadius, NumberOfStages, EBStages,S, TriggerLatency);
    //Bob.SlowerFlight(LOST, Time, ToFSignal12, Phi, TimeArray, DeltaT, AXxDT12, AYxDT12, AZxDT12, Xnumber, Ynumber, Znumber, DetectionPosition, IrisWidth, LaserRadius, NumberOfStages, EBStages, S, TriggerLatency);

}

/**********Ending Calculation **********************/


//Alice.MoleculeEnsemble_Drawer();

/*
Alice.MoleculeEnsemble_Averager(Average32);
Bob.MoleculeEnsemble_Averager(Average12);

cout << "Processor: " << mynode << "\t" << sqrt(pow(Average32[3],2)+pow(Average32[4],2)) << ", " << sqrt(pow(Average12[3],2)+pow(Average12[4],2)); 
cout << " Mean = " << Average32[6] << ", " << Average12[6] << endl << endl; 
*/


//Output ToF signal

if(TimeArrayOnly!=1)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii < int(1e7); ii++)
    {
    if(ToFSignal32[ii] > 0 && Time[ii] > 3e-3)
        {
       cout << Time[ii]+TimeOffset << "," << ToFSignal32[ii] << endl;
           //+double(VSD/vZcenter)+38e-6 << "," << ToFSignal32[ii] << endl;
    }

        if(ToFSignal12[ii] > 0 && Time[ii] > 3e-3)
        {
           cout << Time[ii]+TimeOffset << "," << ToFSignal12[ii] << endl;
           //+double(VSD/vZcenter)+38e-6 << "," << ToFSignal12[ii] << endl;
        }

    }
}


if(TimeArrayOnly==1)
{
    for(int ii = 0; ii < NumberOfStages+EBStages+1; ii++)
    {
        cout << ii << "\t" << TimeArray[ii] << "\t" << VExit[ii]  << endl;
        //+double(VSD/vZcenter)+double(265e-6) << "\t" << VExit[ii]  << endl;
    }
}

/*for(int ii = 0; ii < NumberOfStages; ii++)
{
        cout << ii << "\t" << LOST[ii] << endl;
}
*/


/*        
MPI_Finalize();
*/



}
```

Comment: Strip out code until your program works. Most plausible explanation that I can see is the initialization of static objects in your other source files.

Answer (score 2):

You're out of stack space.

You declare very large arrays in your code (over 10 million elements), which are all allocated on the stack. Instead of declaring the arrays statically, use dynamic memory allocation. So, instead of

```
double Time[int(1e7)];
```

write

```
double* Time;
Time = new double[int(1e7)];
```

and hope to have enough RAM in your computer :)

Comment: Yes, thanks buc! After switching the Time array and various other 3D arrays to dynamic allocation, I am now successfully running my simulation. I'm guessing this was originally used on a powerful compute cluster I have access to which had much higher static allocation limits.